# Changing div height according to window height

Tags: html, css, position

I've a html structure like:-

```
<body>
    <div class="header">header</div>
    <div class="content">
        hello
    </div>
    <div class="footer">footer</div>
</body>
```

And the applied style on it are:-

```
<style>
        body {
            padding: 0px !important;
            margin: 0px !important;
        }
        .header {
            height: 30px;
            background: gray;
        }
        .footer {
            height: 30px;
            background: green;
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0px;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .content{
            background: yellow;
        }


    </style>
```

What I want is, the content div's height will be equal to the full height of the window except the header & footer part. Currently I'm just seeing a small yellow strip for the content part, as the text within it very minimal, the rest of the page is white. I want, the content div will occupy that place.  I tried to use height : 100%; in the content div, but it didn't work. please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to modify your content class like:-

```
     .content{
            background: yellow;
            position: fixed;
            width: 100%;
            top: 30px;
            bottom: 30px;
        }
```

The top and bottom is 30px as the height of header and footer is 30px. it'll work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try making a div class="wrapper" that surrounds your div class="content"... In the css give the .wrapper 100% width and height. I hope that helps.